# How to delete a corrupt database from azure sql

Tags: sql, azure

I have tried to delete a SQL database from the azure portal. It looks like it has failed part way though. The database doesn't show up under the list of SQL servers in the Azure portal. However if I login to the server through SSMS it is still there. I now can't delete the database or create a new one with that name.

I've tried deleting the database with a query and get an error saying the database doesn't exits. If I try to create it either from the Azure portal or SSMS it gets an error saying it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, with SSL settings, where it would return that it is linked to the app even tho it wasn't, hence I was not able to delete it. After a couple of weeks of back and forward with the support, we removed it through [azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com).

How to:

1. Once you are logged in, set read/write
2. In serach box find your resource
3. Click actions (POST/DELETE) // these should be available now since you have set read/write
4. Click Delete

Hopefully, this would help anyone who has any corrupted resources in Azure.

Comment: The database is not showing up anywhere in the resource explorer. It looks like is has somehow become orphaned!

Comment: Then it seems like its support ticket time. If you/your company does not own the support package, you can contact them on twitter with your problem, and explain that you do not own support package, and they will give you one free support ticket since it is an error on their side.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help

Comment: About 7pm that night the table finally was removed.